# Issue with Left Outer Join in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, left-join

I am using the below query to fetch the data.

```
select t2.tailnum,  t2.year, avg(t1.ddelay) from otp_data t1 left outer join plane_data t2 on trim(t1.tn) = trim(t2.tailnum) group by t2.tailnum;
```

But receiving the below error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 1:23 Invalid column reference 'year'
```

Please guide me the reason for this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `t2.year` in `Group by`.

```
select t2.tailnum,  t2.year, avg(t1.ddelay) from otp_data t1 left outer join plane_data t2 on trim(t1.tn) = trim(t2.tailnum) group by t2.tailnum, t2.year;
```